# Python Post Request 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: json, python-3.x, post, http-status-code-400

I am using requests module in Python for the above format data. I tried all the below options. Nothing is working. It still throws 400 Bad Request.

```
import requests
import json

data = {"AlertTime": "2022-01-28T15:11:53.5873988Z", "ComputerDnsName": "was-75", "AlertTitle": "Ongoing hands-on-keyboard attacker activity detected (Cobalt Strike)"}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Splunk XXXXX',"Content-type": "application/json",}
url = 'https://http-inputs-XXX.splunkcloud.com/services/collector'

response = requests.post(url,XXX,headers=headers,)
print(response.status_code, response.reason)

Below are tried options for XXX in response
json={'json_payload': data}
data = json.dumps(data)
json=data
data=str(data)
data=json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")
```

What other options can be checked to fix this?

Comment: it depends on what your server is expecting. For example, your request may be syntaxically correct but your endpoint expect the data to be passed with keyword `payload` instead of `data`.  
can you complete your question with the snippet of your request ?

Comment: I have updated the sample snippet.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

Comment: how about just `requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)` as @Linga 's link suggests (without castig to string or using json.dump) ?  
otherwise it's likely your endpoint who require something quite specific